# What is the best way to Dispose the connection with MvvmCross and the SQLite Plugin

Tags: c#, mvvmcross, sqlite-net

I would like to know if the MvvmCross container can handle the disposal of the SQLite connection or should this be done manually in the repository.

I have seen code examples like the following that don't manually dispose or close the SQLite connection:

```
public class ExampleRepository
{
    private readonly ISQLiteConnection _connection;

    public ExampleRepository(ISQLiteConnectionFactory factory)
    {
        _connection = factory.Create("Example.db");
        _connection.CreateTable<Example>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Example> All()
    {
        return _connection.Table<Example>().ToList();
    }
}
```

**Would this be a better option?**

```
public class ExampleRepository
{
    private readonly ISQLiteConnectionFactory _factory;

    public ExampleRepository(ISQLiteConnectionFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Example> All()
    {
        using (var connection = _factory.Create("Example.db"))
        {
            connection.CreateTable<Example>();
            return connection.Table<Example>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Would it be better to use a using block to dispose of the connection each time it is used in the the repository?

Or is it more overhead to keep creating and disposing the connection. Hence the reason for leaving it open in the first example?

Comment: you should always dispose of the connection after usage - any usage. same applies for objects that implement IDisposable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in instantiate any `IDisposable` object, you can do so with a `using` statement. Any time the execution returns from the scope of a `using`, the object will be disposed. This includes returns and exceptions.

```
using (var obj = new Connection()) {
    throw new Exception("This will dispose of obj");
}
```

When you build a class that needs a persistent `IDisposable` object like yours, you should also make your own class `IDisposable`, and dispose of those objects in the `Dispose()` method:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    Connection con = new Connection();
    public void Dispose()
    {
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then when you instantiate your own class, use `using`, and everything will be happily disposed of when appropriate.

```
using (var obj = new MyClass()) {
    throw new Exception("This will dispose of obj, and obj.con");
}
```

Ultimately, the later solution is best, because:

- you create resources when necessary
- reuse them efficiently
- and dispose of them properly

Comment: Of course, this assumes your ExampleRepository class doesn't need to stick around.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be better to use a using block to dispose of the connection
>   each time it is used in the the repository?

**YES** it is always good to use `using{}` block(for the classes which implemet `IDisposable` interface) as it will make sure that `object` willbe disposed once it leaves the block.

```
using (var connection = _factory.Create("Example.db"))
    {
        connection.CreateTable<Example>();
        return connection.Table<Example>().ToList();
    }//dispose here
```